# What exactly is a "message" in terms of application insights data?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to fine tune my application insights cost, it's currently about 80% of the cost of running my service. When I look at the "usage and estimated costs" charts I can see most of my data volume is "message" but I can't find any information on what this actually means.

[image]

My app is predominantly Azure Functions that interact with various queues, etc. I can't see a table in the Logs that represent this data so I'm a bit lost as to what this could be or how I might reduce the cost of this in app insights.

I could add samping, etc. but I'd prefer to understand the problem better before doing that.

**So what exactly is a "message" in application insights and how can I view this raw data?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A message is the same as a Trace, example can be seen in this screenshot ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/diagnostic-search)):

[image]

Azure functions generate a lot of trace telemetry. [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories) shows what kind of logging is send to the trace table in application insights. You can [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) the telemetry but be aware that it might break some things like dependency logging. The [log category list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) shows what is logged at what level. Use it as a guidance.

Comment: Bit confusing that they seem to call it "message" in one place and "trace" somewhere else.

Comment: some of this is historic, or depends on what kind of service is generating the data and what it is called there.  some of the sdks have `traceMessage` as a function, some have `trackTrace`.  the underlying table name in app insights is literally `traces`, with a field `message`.